# Magento 2 store switcher - store cookie not changing because of full page cache

Tags: magento2, multistore, full-page-cache, cookie, store-switcher

I have a Magento 2 site with a basic store switcher that lets the user switch between 2 stores using the URL method (e.g __store=default).

When I have FPC enabled, the cookie that sets the current store doesn't update when I change the store using the switcher and then when Ichange page I see the previous store currency.

Without resorting to hole punching and thus breaking FPC, does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: What is your Magento version?

Comment: What was the solution? can you please post answer I have similar issue.

Comment: In the end I was using the wrong store switcher code. I no longer have access to this codebase. Magento 2 has two "store switcher" files, make sure you use the right one (I can't remember which one it is now, it's been a while)